# Laravel Scout - multi language

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, elasticsearch, full-text-search

I am wondering what is the best approach to index translations with **Laravel Scout**.

In my current project I have a different index for each language (Ex: **main-en/pages**; **main-fr/pages**) so it is easy to search.

With **Laravel Scout** each model is synchronized with an index and the only way I see is to index translations as a "nested relation" and I am not sure how to configure mapping (analyzers etc.) to query a specific language

Comment: I believe my answer here can be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44154065/1001125

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multi-language indexes with Laravel Scout and Algolia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44071033/multi-language-indexes-with-laravel-scout-and-algolia)